# How to equalize spaces between buttons?

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to equalize spaces between four buttons. Is there any way this could be done? The problem is that first and last buttons needs to be near the edge, and the remaining space should be equally divided for remaining two buttons and three spaces.

[image]

layout/main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/setupButtons"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/setupButtonA1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_arrow_up"
            android:enabled="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/setupButtonA2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_arrow_down"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:enabled="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/setupButtonB1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_arrow_up"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:enabled="false" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/setupButtonB2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_arrow_down"
            android:enabled="false" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

Thank you for all of your answers, the correct **solution** was:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/setupButtons"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/setupButtonA1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_arrow_up"
        android:enabled="true" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/setupButtonA2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_arrow_down"
        android:enabled="true" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/setupButtonB1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_arrow_up"
        android:enabled="false" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/setupButtonB2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_arrow_down"
        android:enabled="false" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use below code in which i have inserted blank views with weight 1 set in  all the controls in linearlayout.

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
<Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" android:layout_weight="1"/>
 <View
            android:id="@+id/v2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" android:layout_weight="1"/>
 <View
            android:id="@+id/v2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" android:layout_weight="1"/>
 <View
            android:id="@+id/v2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Adding blank Views solved my problem, however giving every element weight of 1 makes them equal in size, which makes spaces equal with buttons, and that is not what I wanted. I've made buttons without weight and gave all blank Views weight of 1 and width 0dp so spaces now equally divide the remaining width. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Try `android:layout_weight="0"`

Answer (score 0):

Use android:weightSum="4" this should define in layout, this is missing in ur code.
and define android:layout_weight="1" for each button

```
 <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
         android:weightSum="4"> /////------ i made changes here

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/setupButtonA2" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:background="@drawable/button_arrow_down" 
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:enabled="true" /> 

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/setupButtonB1" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:background="@drawable/button_arrow_up" 
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:enabled="false" /> 
       <Button 
            android:id="@+id/setupButtonB1" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:background="@drawable/button_arrow_up" 
            android:layout_weight="0.5" 
            android:enabled="false" /> 

       <Button 
            android:id="@+id/setupButtonB1" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:background="@drawable/button_arrow_up" 
            android:layout_weight="0.5" 
            android:enabled="false" /> 

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"` in your

```
android:id="@+id/setupButtonA2"  and       
     android:id="@+id/setupButtonB1"
```

Change the dp value as your layout fits

Answer (score 0):

I will not bother to write sample code as the others did here, instead I'll just explain how I'd do it.

The whole button strip (width fill_parent, height wrap_content) will be a RelativeLayout.
Add the first button, set layout_alignParentLeft=true
Add the next button, set layout_alignParentRight=true (this will be the last button on the strip)
Add a LinearLayout(fill_parent, wrap_content), toLeftOf=lastButton, toRightOf=firstButton. this should place it in the middle of the two buttons. Set its orientation to horizontal.
Inside this LinearLayout, add two new LinearLayouts **(layout_width="0dip"**, layout_height=wrap_content). Set layout_weight=1. Set gravity=center.
Inside these two LinearLayouts, place your remaining buttons.

No need to set weightSum for any layout. All buttons are (wrap_content, wrap_content), or as you'd like their size to be.